# How do I strip file extensions from files found with find in MacOS shell

Tags: macos, find

I'm about to batch-convert a number of HEIC files to JPG format using ImageMagick.

The conversion needs to be able to travers sub-folders.

I figured out something like this:

```
find . -iname "*.HEIC" | mogrify -format jpg $f
```

but it doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,

Newbee

Comment: `Mogrify` overwrites the original image file, whereas, `convert` writes to a different image file. Perhaps you should be using convert and outputting a `.jpg`?

Comment: Sure, Magick convert is the right one, but I can't find out how to strip the extension for the output file.

I.e.  sort of:

find . -name "*HEIC*" | magick convert $f    <$f without the extension+.jpg"

Comment: [bash - How can I remove the extension of a filename in a shell script? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12152626/how-can-i-remove-the-extension-of-a-filename-in-a-shell-script)